# Classic and Claims authentication under migration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, claims-based-auth, content-migration

I need to know if the following is possible:

I am migrating some DBs from SP2010 to a whole new SP 2013 farm/environment. My steps are:

1. Create a classic Web App in the SP2013 farm
2. Restore 2010 DBs to the new SQL server
3. Test the DBs against the 2013 Web App
4. Mount the DBs to the 2013 Web App
5. Convert to Claims

Now the question is, if I have done this job last month, and I now want to get it up to date with backup-files of the 2010 DB, would it be possible just to roll the backup out on the 2013 Claims Web App.

Or do I have to clean up/delete everything from my SP2013 farm and then again do the migration process?

I really hope that I do not have to go with the last.

Comment: No, it would not be possible. When you have attached the old database to a 2013 application and converted it, changes are made in the database. So you would need to re-do the process to be able to use a old backup.

Comment: @user19952, please use "Your Answer" section for providing answer. This way its easier to mark it as answer, thus helping others.

Comment: @bkk, i did not feel that that short line was really the answer Emo was looking for, more as a short and quick answer. Leaving the opportunity for anyone else to write a longer and more detailed answer.